# Binding current context of ICollection<T> in ListView to combo box

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listview, binding

#### Background

I need to allow users to edit an `IList<Move> moves` where `Move` is an immutable class.  Users choose moves from a drop-down (`ComboBox`).  For example:

```
[[ for every move slot ]]
    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource MoveCollection}" SelectedValue="[[ move of the move slot ]]" />
[[ end for ]]
```

#### My approach

I am using a `ListView` to iterate over the collection, and a `DataTemplate` to create the `ComboBox` instances, as follows:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Moves}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource MoveCollection}" SelectedValue="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I get an exception with this ("Two-way binding requires Path or XPath."), so I resorted to the following binding expression for `SelectedValue`:

```
{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}
```

This makes it compile and run.  However, the `moves` collection is not updated as the user makes changes.  Obviously, only the data context is being changed, not the actual value.

I believe this is an issue because the `IList<Move>` is simply treated as a read-only collection by WPF, and changes to the combo box's value do not and cannot modify that collection.  In code, WPF cannot do the following:

```
moves[x] = Resources["MoveCollection"][y];
```

I would like for changes in the combo box's value to update the `moves` collection.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your suspicions about IList are partially correct. Let's take a look at what's actually happening under the hood:
ListView is handed a collection of items. For each item, it creates a new copy of the data template within a panel specified by the panel template. The data template is going to be handed a reference to the object it's interested in as its DataContext. So even if you changed the value successfully, the underlying scenario looks like this in C#:

List yourItems = ...;
foreach(string yourItem in yourItems)
{
   someControl.DataContext = yourItem;

//you change it here
   someControl.DataContext = yourNewItem;
}

You wouldn't expect the above code to change the list. Although it's a bit different, I think what's going on here is similar.

I believe the simplest way to do what you're trying to do would be to make an IList>. Wrapper would just be a dummy class wrapping a Move. Binding would then change the Move on the Wrapper. On the backend, it'll be trivial to unwrap the list when you need it with a little LINQ.

How's that sound?